# How Coud I get my stats on my graph correctly?

Tags: react-native, date, graph

For my React Native app : I would like obtain Stats on my graph per day and per week. Per day is good but but by week when I click on 'Semaine précédente' I have stats from last week but it's starting by Mardi ( Tuesday ) and Jeudi (Thursday) have 2 dot point.

Could you help me please ?

```
`import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import {
  LineChart,
  BarChart,
} from "react-native-chart-kit";

export default function SuiviScreen() {

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.value);
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  const [statHydrate, setStatHydrate] = useState(null);
  const [statsHydrateWeek, setStatsHydrateWeek] = useState([]);
  const [jour, setJour] = useState(0);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
  const [durée, setDurée] = useState(null);
  const [periodDay, setPeriodDay] = useState(false);
  const [periodWeek, setPeriodWeek] = useState(false);
  const [isThirsty, setIsThirsty] = useState(null); 
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
  const [clickedDay, setClickedDay] = useState(null);
  const[valueClickedDay, setValueClickedDay] = useState(null);
  const [firstDayOfWeek, setFirstDayOfWeek] = useState(moment().startOf('isoWeek'));
  const [statsHydrateWeekPrev, setStatsHydrateWeekPrev] = useState([]);
const [statsHydrateWeekNext, setStatsHydrateWeekNext] = useState([]);
  const [dropDownValue, setDropDownValue] = useState({});
  const currentDate = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  const inputPeriod = [   { label: 'Jour', value: '1' },{ label: 'Semaine', value: '2' },]

  const chartConfigDay = {
    backgroundGradientFrom: "red",
    backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 0,
    backgroundGradientTo: "red",
    backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0,
    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(38, 70, 83, ${opacity})`,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    barPercentage: 2,
    useShadowColorFromDataset: false,
    yAxisSuffix: "",
    yAxisOrigin: 0,
    yAxisMin: 0,
    decimalPlaces: 2,
    propsForDots: {
      r: "5",
      strokeWidth: "1",
      stroke: "#E76F51"
    },
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (dropDownValue.label === 'Jour' || dropDownValue.label === undefined) {
      setPeriodDay(true);
      setPeriodWeek(false);
    fetch(`http://192.168.1.132:3000/stats/getFeedback/${user.token}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.data.length > 0) {
          const lastStat = data.data[data.data.length - 1 - jour];
          setStatHydrate(lastStat.Hydratation_quantity);
          setDate(lastStat.Date);
          setIsThirsty(lastStat.Thirsty_feel);
          setDurée(data.data.length);
        }
      })
    }
    else if (dropDownValue.label === 'Semaine' || dropDownValue.label === undefined) {
      setPeriodDay(false);
      setPeriodWeek(true);
      
      fetch(`http://192.168.1.132:3000/stats/getFeedback/${user.token}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.data.length > 0) {
        
       
  
        const prevWeekData = data.data.filter(stat => {
          const statDate = moment(stat.Date);
         
          return statDate.isBetween(
            moment(firstDayOfWeek).subtract(1, 'week').startOf('day'), // Début de la semaine précédente
            moment(firstDayOfWeek).startOf('day') // Fin de la semaine précédente
          );
        });
        
  
        setStatsHydrateWeekPrev(prevWeekData);

        const nextWeekData = data.data.filter(stat => {
          const statDate = moment(stat.Date);
        
          return statDate.isBetween(
            moment(firstDayOfWeek).add(7, 'days').startOf('day'), // Début de la semaine suivante
            moment(firstDayOfWeek).add(14, 'days').startOf('day') // Fin de la semaine suivante
          );
        });

        setStatsHydrateWeekNext(nextWeekData);

  
// Filtrer les statistiques de la semaine actuelle
        const currentWeekStats = data.data.filter(stat => {
          const statDate = moment(stat.Date);
          return statDate.isBetween(
            firstDayOfWeek, // Début de la semaine actuelle
            moment(firstDayOfWeek).add(7, 'days') // Fin de la semaine actuelle
          );
        });

        // Trier les statistiques par date
        const sortedStats = currentWeekStats.sort((a, b) => moment(a.Date) - moment(b.Date));

        // Filtrer les jours sans feedback
        const filteredStats = sortedStats.filter(stat => stat.Date !== null);

        // const hydrateData = filteredStats.map(stat => stat.Hydratation_quantity);

        const hydrateData = filteredStats.map(stat => ({
          date: stat.Date,
          hydratation_quantity: stat.Hydratation_quantity
        }));
        setStatsHydrateWeek(hydrateData);

        

        // Utiliser la première date avec feedback dans la semaine
        setDate(filteredStats.length > 0 ? filteredStats[0].Date : null);
        setIsThirsty(filteredStats.length > 0 ? filteredStats[0].Thirsty_feel : null);
        setDurée(data.data.length);
      }
    });
}
    
  }, [jour, dropDownValue ]); 


  const jourPrécédent = () => {
    if (jour < durée - 1) {
      setJour(prevJour => prevJour + 1);
    }
  }
  const jourSuivant = () => {
    if (jour > 0) {
      setJour(prevJour => prevJour - 1);
    }
  }

  const HydratePourcentageDay = {
    labels: [ "Quantité d'eau bue en Cl" ],
    
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [ statHydrate]
      },
    ],
  };

  const chartConfigWeek = {
    backgroundGradientFrom: "red",
    backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 0,
    backgroundGradientTo: "red",
    backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0,
    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(38, 70, 83, ${opacity})`,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    barPercentage: 2,
    useShadowColorFromDataset: false,
    yAxisSuffix: "",
    yAxisOrigin: 0,
    yAxisMin: 0,
    decimalPlaces: 2,
    propsForDots: {
      r: "5",
      strokeWidth: "1",
      stroke: "#E76F51"
    },
    showYAxisLabel: false,
  }
 
  // const filteredStatsHydrateWeek = statsHydrateWeek.filter(stat => moment(stat.Date).isSameOrBefore(moment(), 'day'));


  const daysOfWeek = ["Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam", "Dim"];
  const HydratePourcentageWeek = {
    
    datasets: [
      {
        data: statsHydrateWeek.map(stat => stat.hydratation_quantity)
        
      },
    ],
    legend: ["Quantité d'eau bue en Cl"]
  };
  
  const semainePrécédente = () => {
    if (statsHydrateWeek.length > 0) {
      const newDate = moment(firstDayOfWeek).subtract(1, 'week').startOf('isoWeek');
     
      setFirstDayOfWeek(newDate);
      setJour(prevJour => prevJour + 7);
      console.log('Nouvelle date :', newDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    }
    setClickedDay(null);
  };
  
  const semaineSuivante = () => {
    if (statsHydrateWeek.length > 0 && moment().isAfter(firstDayOfWeek, 'day')) {
      const newDate = moment(firstDayOfWeek).add(7, 'days');
      setFirstDayOfWeek(newDate);
      setJour(prevJour => prevJour - 7);
    }  
    setClickedDay(null);
  };

  const handleDataPointClick = (index) => {
    // Récupérer le jour correspondant à l'index du point de données
    const dateCliquee = moment(statsHydrateWeek[index].date).locale('fr').format('dddd');
    const majDay = dateCliquee.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dateCliquee.slice(1).toLowerCase();

    const valueDay = statsHydrateWeek[index].hydratation_quantity;
  
    // Afficher le jour concerné
    setClickedDay(majDay);
    setValueClickedDay(valueDay);
  
  };

 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.titlePage}>Suivi Screen</Text>
      <Dropdown
        style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && { borderColor: 'blue' }]}
        inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
        data={inputPeriod}
        search
        maxHeight={300}
        labelField="label"
        valueField="value"
        placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Filtrez par période' : '...'}
        searchPlaceholder="Search..."
        value={dropDownValue.value}
        onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
        
        xLabelsOffset={100}
        onChange={item => {
          setDropDownValue(item);
          setIsFocus(false);
          
          

        }} />
        {periodDay && 
        <View>
      <View style={styles.divBtn}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => jourPrécédent()} style={styles.btnPeriod}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Jour précédent</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => jourSuivant()} style={styles.btnPeriod}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Jour suivant</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.graphContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.titleGraph}>Hydratation</Text>
          <Text style={styles.descriptionGraph}>{currentDate}</Text>
          <BarChart
            data={HydratePourcentageDay}
            width={screenWidth}
            height={250}
            yAxisLabel=""
            chartConfig={chartConfigDay}
            verticalLabelRotation={0}
            fromZero={true}
            showValuesOnTopOfBars={false}
          />
          {isThirsty ? <Text style={styles.descriptionGraph}>Sensation de soif : Oui </Text> : <Text style={styles.descriptionGraph}>Sensation de soif : Non</Text>}
          
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
}
{periodWeek && statsHydrateWeek.length > 0 && (
        <View>
      <View style={styles.divBtn}>
      {statsHydrateWeekPrev.length > 0 && (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => semainePrécédente()} style={styles.btnPeriod}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Semaine précédente</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      {statsHydrateWeekNext.length > 0 && (
  <TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => semaineSuivante()} 
    style={styles.btnPeriod}
  >
    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Semaine Suivante</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)} 
      </View>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.graphContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.titleGraph}>Hydratation</Text>
          <Text style={styles.descriptionGraph}> Semaine du : {currentDate}</Text>
          <LineChart
            data={HydratePourcentageWeek}
            width={screenWidth}
            height={250}
            yAxisLabel=""
            chartConfig={chartConfigWeek}
            verticalLabelRotation={30}
            fromZero={true}
            showValuesOnTopOfBars={false}
            onDataPointClick={({ index }) => handleDataPointClick(index)}
          />
          <View style={styles.divLabel}>
  <Text style={styles.clickedDay}>{clickedDay ? `Quantité bue ${clickedDay} : ${valueClickedDay} cL ` : 'Veuillez cliquer sur un point pour connaitre le jour concerné.'}</Text>
</View>
          {/* {isThirsty ? <Text style={styles.descriptionGraph}>Sensation de soif : Oui </Text> : <Text style={styles.descriptionGraph}>Sensation de soif : Non</Text>} */}
          
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
     
      </View>
      )}
      <Text style={styles.astuce}>Scrollez pour voir les autres graphiques</Text>
      
     
    </View>
  );
}
```

It's my code , I tried to modify ' firstDayWeek'  but nothing to work. The goal is to have stats only on Day who have received a feedback, for example, for the currentweek it's work fine because 3 days have feedback and only 3 days have dot points on my graph. What's more, the first point is monday , but when I clicked on 'Semaine précédente' There are stats based on the previous week but I don't know it's start by Tuesday and Thursday have 2 dot points with same value.